# how to get the current item being written by an XMLWriter

Tags: c#, xml

I have a series of settings being written out by an XMLWriter in C#. Here's some code:

```
        try
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = ("    ");
            using (writer = XmlWriter.Create("PCOB2NET.XML", settings))
            {
                // Write XML data.
                writer.WriteStartElement("PowerCOBOL2NETMigration");
                writer.WriteStartElement("config");
                writer.WriteElementString("VSVersion", selectedVSver);
                writer.WriteElementString("path2SelectedVSVerProjects", path2SelectedVSVerProjects);
                if (path2VSoverridden)
                    writer.WriteElementString("path2VSoverridden", "true");
                else
                    writer.WriteElementString("path2VSoverridden", "false");
                writer.WriteElementString("path2PRCfile", path2PRCfile);
                writer.WriteElementString("path2XMLfile", path2XMLfile);
                writer.WriteElementString("path2VSProject", path2VSProject);
```

... and so on.
My problem is that if there is an Exception (like a null field, for instance) it goes to the catch block and reports the exception as we would expect, but I don't know WHICH field it was writing at the time.

My question:

Is there any way I can get the current string being written, when an Exception occurs? I searched the web without success and I looked through every property and method of XMLWriter but I can't find a way to do it. Is there maybe a certain type of Exception trap that will give it to me? Any help or thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq which is a new Net Library for reading and writing xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string selectedVSver = "";
            string path2SelectedVSVerProjects = "";
            Boolean path2VSoverridden = true;
            string path2PRCfile = "";
            string path2XMLfile = "";
            string path2VSProject = "";

            XDocument doc = new XDocument();

            XElement powerCOBOL2NETMigration = new XElement("PowerCOBOL2NETMigration", new object[] {
                new XElement("config", new object[] {
                    new XElement("VSVersion", selectedVSver),
                    new XElement("path2SelectedVSVerProjects", path2SelectedVSVerProjects),
                    new XElement("path2VSoverridden", path2VSoverridden),
                    new XElement("path2PRCfile", path2PRCfile),
                    new XElement("path2XMLfile", path2XMLfile),
                    new XElement("path2VSProject", path2VSProject)
                })
            });
            doc.Add(powerCOBOL2NETMigration);

            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a LINQ fan so I was interested to see the code you posted. Thanks. However, I'm not sure how this addresses the actual problem I have. I can certainly add the settings to the XML file as blocks, but if there is an error (like a null field) it may still give me improperly formed XML and I still won't know which field caused the problem. Even if I manage to write the file without problem, whatever reads it is going to have to deal with it so I think it just moves the problem. It is right that there SHOULD be an exception thrown; my problem is knowing WHICH field causes it to be thrown.

Comment: You should never have a null exception.  It is a programming error which should be fixed before the application is released.  Using XmlWriter is not the preferred method.  You have to properly balance the open tags with the closing tags.  Linq the closing tags are automatically handled.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It threw an error because there was a x00 character in a field, not because the field was null. I tried null fields and they worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to wrap  small helper methods around XmlWriter.WriteStartElement etc. and catch your exceptions there.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. I also considered checking every field for null before presenting it to the XMLWriter. Unfortunately, if you have around 200 fields, neither of these is an attractive option... Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was looking for a solution at the wrong end of the problem. Instead of puzzling over XMLWriter, what I SHOULD have done was investigate the EXCEPTION.
(I did do this but only for the Exception Class, I needed to look further.) The problem looked like it could be easily solved by nesting some exception catch blocks, so:

```
        catch (ArgumentNullException anEx)
        {
            // retrieve the offending field name from anEX...
            badField = anEx.ParamName;
```

...
            }

```
        catch (ArgumentException aEx)
        {
            // retrieve the offending field name from aEX...
            badField = aEx.ParamName;
```

...
            }

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
```

...

However, I was misled by the "ParamName" which does not mean what I thought it did... This always returned null and I was no better off.

After spending a number of hours reading everything I could about Exception handling in C#, I am much better informed, but no wiser. I can't find a solution with the Framework so I have little recourse but to push all the settings through a method which will do the actual write and trap any exception at that moment, with the offending field available as it will have been passed into that method.

I think this inelegant, but I can't spend more time on it. Many thanks to all who responded and those who thought about responding... :-) I'll leave this open in case somebody really has a solution, for a few days.